# Difference between get_by_natural_key and natural_key

Tags: python, django, django-models, natural-key

As I understand, the model manager's get_by_natural_key is used in deserialization and the natural_key is used in serialization. Is this true ? If not what are the differences ?

And also, do we need to give the --natural-foreign and --natural-primary key always ? Are there any way to force serializing/deserializing via natural key ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, Django uses `get_by_natural_key` for deserialization and `natural_key` for serialization.

As stated in the documentation you don't need to define both of them. You can safely use only one of them.

If you need to serialize your model using natural keys inside your code you have to use `serializers.serialize()` with `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` and/or `use_natural_primary_keys=True`.

If you need to serialize/deserialize some objects using natural keys and `admin.py dumpdata` then you have to pass `--natural-foreign` and/or `--natural-primary` if you don't they will be serialized/deserialized with default (non natural) behavior.

To "force" natural keys in `dumpdata` you can create a shell alias.

If you need more advanced model serialization/deserialization I suggest you to use an external component like [Django REST Framework serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers) or write your own one.